# Applying DataTemplate based on type

Tags: c#, wpf

when i do the following and set the content of a Control to my ViewModel the Template gets applied automatically.

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ViewModel}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
              <ControlX ....>
              <ControlY ....>
        </StackPanel>
 </DataTemplate>
```

however i want to use FindResource to get the DataTemplate in the code behind so i had to add an x:key

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ViewModel}" x:Key="{x:Type ViewModels:ViewModel}">
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ViewModel}" x:Key="ViewModelTemplate">
```

But when i add an x:key the FindResource() works but the DataTemplate stops being applied automatically based on the type, any workaround available for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Task}">
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TaskName}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Priority}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

> This DataTemplate gets applied automatically to all Task objects. Note that in this case the x:Key is set implicitly. Therefore, if you assign this DataTemplate an x:Key value, you are overriding the implicit x:Key and the DataTemplate would not be applied automatically.

It works as [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Styling_DataType). AFAIK you can either use Key or DataType not both, there may be workarounds which I wasn't aware of.

Comment: if they say so then i expect `window.FindResource(typeof(Task)) as DataTemplate` to work, but it doesnt

Comment: They say that key is set implicitly, so we need to know what that implicit key is. Honestly I don't know that sorry:(

Comment: worth giving a try `typeof(Task).FullName`, `typeof(Task).Name` etc

Answer (score 2):

As a bad looking work around, you may try creating 2 `DataTemplate`s that share the same content:

This ControlTemplate defines the shared content:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}"
                 x:Key="MyControlTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="Some content" />
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then 2 DataTemplates as a workaround:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
    <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource MyControlTemplate}" />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:String}">
    <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource MyControlTemplate}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

---

**Edit:**

I know that this answer came a year too late after I've provided a bad looking work around above, but it's better than never.

The implicit key set for an implicit data template is the data type itself wrapped in a `DataTemplateKey`.

You can either use:

```
FindResource(new DataTemplateKey(typeof (MainViewModel))
```

or

```
Resource[new DataTemplateKey(typeof (MainViewModel)]
```

to get your data template in code behind.